# $X$ is not a simple random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I have problems with this exercise of probability.

Let $X$ be a random variable defined on Lebesgue measure
on $[0,1]$, and suppose that $X$ is a one-to-one function. Prove that $X$ is not a simple random variable.

I think I must prove this by contradiction, but I cannot conclude anything.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and note that, since $X$ is one-to-one, there must be a unique $\omega \in [0,1]$ such that $X(\omega)=x$. This gives us that
$$\mathbb{P}(X=x) = \mathbb{P}(\{\omega\}) = 0$$
where $\mathbb{P}$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. Since this must hold for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $X$ cannot be simple.

Answer (score 2):

The simple random variables are exactly the measurable functions with finite range, so there you have it.

Comment: I do not see how this prove the statement.

Comment: @Bayesianguy it follows immediately from the definition of simple random variables

Comment: but this is contradictory because the random variable is defined on lebesgue measue?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the collection of (Borel) subsets of $[0,1]$, on which $X(\omega)$ have distinct values on each set. We have seen that the cardinality of this set is at least countable: it must contain each rational number! But for simple random variables, we only have this set to be finite.